# Como lograr "Move to backgroud" en react native

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

Quiero lograr que cuando haga BackPress en android se mande la app para background pero no se cierre del todo, porque cuando le doy al icono para volver a abrir recarga todo desde cero.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Te recomiendo leer [ask], [answer] y hacer el [tour]. Aquí seguimos un ***ESTRICTO*** modelo de ***PREGUNTAS y RESPUESTAS***. Lo que acabas de hacer, es una pregunta, y sin embargo no preguntas nada y ofreces una respuesta!! Eso no es correcto, puesto que no sigue el formato del sitio. Lo que ***SI*** es posible es que hagas una pregunta y te respondas tú mismo!! Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta y dejarla como tal, es decir, una pregunta, y a continuación añadir la respuesta en una *respuesta*! Así se podrá encontrar tu pregunta y su respuesta en los buscadores!

Comment: Gracias @Benito-B así lo haré

Answer (score 0):

**Lo Logré**

Se soluciona creando un modulo de react native, nunca lo habia hecho y casi no encontre informacion sobre como hacer esto en especifico entonces lo publico todo junto por si a alguien le sirve despues

1. crear MoveAppToBackground.java en

   android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\MoveAppToBackground.java
2. Agrega este codigo a MoveAppToBackground.java

```
package com.myapp;
import android.app.Activity;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;

class MoveAppToBackground extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "MoveAppToBackground";
    }

        private ReactContext mReactContext;

    public MoveAppToBackground(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
                mReactContext = reactContext;
    }

    /* React Methods */
   @ReactMethod
    public void MoveToBackground() {
                Activity activity = mReactContext.getCurrentActivity();
                activity.moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
}
```

3. crear android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\MoveAppToBackgroundPackage.java
4. agregar esto a MoveAppToBackgroundPackage.java

```
package com.myapp;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MoveAppToBackgroundPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new MoveAppToBackground(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }

    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Arrays.asList();
    }
}
```

5. Agrega estas lineas a MainApplication.java

```
import com.myapp.MoveAppToBackgroundPackage; <-- this import
...
....
.....
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          packages.add(new MoveAppToBackgroundPackage()); <------ this line
          return packages;
        }
```

**Al final se usa asi en tu app:**

```
import { NativeModules } from "react-native";

const myModule = NativeModules.MoveAppToBackground;

export const moveToBackground = () => {
  // Add your additional custom logic here
  return myModule.MoveToBackground();
};

// You can directly export this and access it
export default myModule;
```